# Setting an Image along with the text in a table cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

How to set an Image in the Table cell along with the text.The image should be at the end of the cell.

Comment: There is a property cell.imageView you can assign to it.
cell.imageView.image = imageObject;

Comment: another way is, subclass the UITableview cell there by u can get full flexibility u can do whatever u want

Comment: You mean Customizing the entire table view using code right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your `UITableViewCell` has its style set to `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` (which is, not surprisingly, the default), just set its `imageView.image` property:

```
myCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"something.png"];
```

Comment: Thank you...I couldn't find the right solution from google.So I decided to do here.I was not an expert in coding just a beginner.Learning everything through internet.But for this I couldn't find the solution thats why I posted here.